# Como calcular a similaridade entre dois textos usando word embedding em Python?

Tags: python

Estou usando `word embedding` do `polyglot` para calcular a similaridade entre dois textos, mas estou com dificuldade para chegar no cálculo da similaridade final.

O método `embedding.distances(word,[words])` retorna a distância de uma palavra para cada palavra que está no vetor. O problema é que não sei identicar qual escala está cada distância calculada pelo `distances`. Essa escala é extramanente importante para  cálculo do índice de similaridade.

```
Similaridade = (soma da distância mínima de cada palavra) / (quantidade de elementos * valor máximo de distância de cada palavra)
```

Não sei como descobrir o `valor máximo da distância de cada palavra`

Comment: De onde você tirou o método para essa fórmula de similaridade? Muito provavelmente essa forma de calcular a similaridade não é compatível com o que a biblioteca polyglot fornece. Nos dê mais dados para conseguirmos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Chegando no trabalho hoje, compartilho o código.

Comment: Edite a pergunta porque aqui não tem formatação.

Comment: Rafael, o método é o distances do Embedding que é um pacote do polyglot. Esse método retorna a distância de uma palavra para um conjunto de palavras que está dentro do vetor. Minha dúvida é: Qual a distância máxima entre uma palavra e outra?

Comment: from polyglot.mapping import Embedding
embeddings = Embedding.load(os.environ['polyglot_data']+r'\embeddings2\pt\embeddings_pkl.tar.bz2')
d = embeddings.distances('Verde', ['Amarelo', 'vermelho', 'azul') )

Comment: Esse cálculo de similaridade é baseado em qual método de distância? Você procurou saber se ele é compatível com o método de distância do polyglot? Eu fui na documentação do polyglot e não há nada referente a cálculo de similaridade e nem mesmo que tipo de método o embedding.distances() utiliza para calcular a distância entre duas palavras. https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Embeddings.html#nearest-neighbors

Comment: A documentação está aqui . https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Embeddings.html

O método que ele utiliza é o Euclidean distance

Comment: E o método de similaridade?

Comment: Não me faz sentido encontrar a distância euclideana máxima entre dois pontos, dado que a distância euclideana pode chegar ao infinito. Verifiquei inclusive no Matering Natural Language Processing with Python e não há nenhum método de similaridade aplicada com a distância euclideana entre palavras. Te aconselho a deixar de lado o polyglot para essa empreitada e procurar nltk.

Comment: Entendi Rafael. Estou começando e é tudo muito novo pra mim. Agora me diz uma coisa. O embbedding tem um método (words) que retorna todas as palavras do corpus. Fiz um script que calcula a distância de entre todas palavras e vai guardando a maior distância dentre todas as comparações. O maior número retornado pelo script foi algo próximo de 2.  Sabendo que as distancias tendem a infinito, o embeddin fornece um método que normaliza as distâncias das palavras.  O método é o normalize_words(). Olhando a definição dele, vi que ele recebe um parâmetro ord que o padrão é 2.

Comment: Só não sei responder se esse parâmetro é a distância máxima que a uma palavra pode ter de outra. Tenho quase certeza que é isso mesmo.

Comment: Vou te ajudar. Espera.

Answer (score 1):

Essa fórmula de similaridade que você está usando não é adequada para o cálculo de distância que a biblioteca `polyglot` te dá. Tem uma outra fórmula de ângulo entre vetores que é mais fácil de aplicar e te dá um resultado entre -1 e 1 e se chama **Cosine Similarity**. Especificamente no lidar com documentos para processamento de linguagem natural, via de regra o vetor é sempre positivo e o resultado da aplicação da *cosine similarity* fica entre 0 e 1.

Basicamente o conceito é o seguinte: há dois vetores, o vetor **w** e o vetor **v**, conforme imagem abaixo. O vetor **v** faz uma projeção (uma sombra) sobre o vetor **w**. O tamanho dessa sombra em relação ao vetor **w** é o que define a similaridade. Quando o valor da projeção é 1, quer dizer que o vetor **v** está exatamente em cima do vetor **w**; ambos são paralelos e idênticos. Quando o valor da projeção é 0, quer dizer que o vetor **v** está a 90° do vetor **w**; ou seja, não possuem similaridade. Se o vetor **v** fosse totalmente pro lado oposto ao de **w**, na direção esquerda, o valor da projeção seria -1; ou seja, o oposto. Como já disse, esperamos apenas valores entre 0 e 1 por causa da [natureza positiva dos vetores](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Cosine_Similarity).

[image: Cosine similarity]

Enfim, como você está começando, vou te dar uma alternativa usando *cosine similarity* para chegar em uma medida de similaridade de palavras. Para começar, tenha a biblioteca `spacy` em seu ambiente. Você pode conseguir ela pelo:

```
pip install -U spacy
```

Como eu acredito que você vai trabalhar com português, baixe também o pacote de modelos da língua e a rede neural convolucional treinada:

```
python -m spacy download pt
python -m spacy download pt_core_news_sm
```

Agora o código para utilizar essa biblioteca:

```
import spacy
# essas bibliotecas abaixo são só para plotar o resultado
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# carregue o modelo
nlp = spacy.load('pt_core_news_sm')

# insira o input sempre em unicode                
palavras = nlp(u'luz claridade amargo salgado')    

dados=[]
for palavra1 in palavras:
    for palavra2 in palavras:
        dados.append(palavra1.similarity(palavra2))    # aqui eu testo a similaridade

# organização dos dados
dados = np.asarray(dados).reshape(len(palavras),len(palavras))
rotulo = [str(palavra) for palavra in palavras]
dados = pd.DataFrame(dados,rotulo,rotulo)

# plotagem
print(dados)
sns.heatmap(dados,annot=True,fmt=".2f",cmap="Blues_r",cbar=False,square=True,xticklabels='auto')
```

Tem muito mais coisa que você pode fazer com essa biblioteca. Procure pelas funcionalidades na [documentação](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) e em [sites que falam sobre ela](https://leportella.com/pt-br/2017/11/30/brincando-de-nlp-com-spacy.html).

E como você diz que está começando e é tudo novo, caso queira se aprofundar mais em processamento de linguagem natural (NLP), recomendo pesquisar mais sobre NLP (tem vários livros bons sobre isso) e as bibliotecas `nltk`, `stanfordcorenlp`, `gensim` e `textblob`.

Comment: Valeu Rafael! Excelente.  Vou testar amanhã. Muito obrigado mesmo. Estou insistindo no embeddings, pois tenho ouvido falar que ele considera o contexto da palavra e melhore significativamente a assertividade do algoritmo de similaridade.

Comment: Se você realmente está interessado em word embedding, procure estudar sobre Word2Vec. A qualidade de uma abordagem dessa vai depender bastante do treinamento da rede neural utilizada. Tem muita coisa pronta por aí, mas nem sempre é adequado a nossa necessidade.

Comment: É importante entender como funciona o conceito de word embedding e como os métodos de Word2Vec e cosine similarity entram na solução. Tem um monte de [artigos](https://medium.com/luizalabs/similaridade-entre-t%C3%ADtulos-de-produtos-com-word2vec-5e26199862f0) e [vídeos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuGRDTuEwxY) que explicam como funciona.